# Passar referencia(?) de planilha para array pra usar em "For" em VBA

Tags: excel-vba

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber se tem como colocar em um array as referencias das tabelas para posteriormente serem utilizadas em uma estrutura "for". Por exemplo:

Arquivo Excel

- planilha1
- Planilha2
- Planilha3

Consigo utilizar o atributo "Name" pra referenciar cada planilha diretamente no codigo, como:

`Planilha1.Range("A5").Value = "50"`

Porém não consigo fazer:

````
For i = 1 to 3
  Planilha(i).Range("A5").Value = "50"

Next```

Existe alguma maneira de percorrer todas as planilhas sem ter que digitar uma por uma?
````

Answer (score -2):

Uma explicação prévia é necessária.

**1.** O VBA Excel tem uma coisa meio confusa. Na barra de propriedades, as planilhas têm duas propriedades com nomes muito similares: `(Name)` e `Name`, e embora elas venham preenchidas iguais quando criamos uma planilha nova, elas podem assumir valores diferentes:

[image: Janela de Propriedades]

A propriedade `(Name)`, que é a primeira da lista, é na verdade o `CodeName`. O usuário não tem contato com o CodeName; só você, desenvolvedor.

Já a propriedade `Name`, que é a penúltima da imagem acima, é o nome da planilha, exatamente o nome que o usuário digitou lá embaixo do Excel, nas abas de seleção das planilhas:

[image: Barra de status do Excel]

A pasta de trabalho acima tem duas planilhas: uma com o `CodeName` plDois (com este nome a gente só interage através do código) e o `Name` Planilha2 (é o que o usuário vê e pode alterar nas abas das planilhas, usar nas fórmulas, etc) e a outra com `CodeName` plTeste e o `Name` PlanilhaT.

**2.** Você pode referenciar as planilhas de algumas formas diferentes. Vamos trabalhar com a pasta de trabalho de exemplo acima.

Para descobrir o `Name` e o `CodeName`, basta usar as propriedades de mesmo nome:

```
Sub testandoNameCodename()
    Debug.Print plTeste.Name ' Retorna PlanilhaT
    Debug.Print plTeste.CodeName ' Retorna plTeste
End Sub
```

Agora veja quantas formas você tem de referenciar a planilha `plTeste`:

```
Sub testandoReferenciarPlanilha()
    Dim arquivo As Workbook, planilha As Worksheet
    Set arquivo = ActiveWorkbook 'Referência ao arquivo do Excel. Não temos certeza de
        'qual arquivo estará selecionado pelo usuário naquele momento, portanto isso
        'deve ser usado com muita cautela.
    Set plan = plTeste
    
    'Referências à mesma planilha:
    Debug.Print plan.Name 'Através de uma variável que aponta para a planilha
    Debug.Print plTeste.Name 'Diretamente pelo CodeName
    Debug.Print arquivo.ActiveSheet.Name 'Através da propriedade ActiveSheet da pasta de trabalho
                        'referenciada pela variável "arquivo", mas não temos certeza de qual planilha estará
                        'selecionada pelo usuário naquele momento, portanto isso deve ser usado com muita cautela.
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name 'Similar ao de cima, mas com referência implícita ao arquivo ativo (ActiveWorkbook)
    Debug.Print arquivo.Sheets("PlanilhaT").Name 'Através do objeto "Sheets" ou "Worksheets", que são a mesma coisa,
    Debug.Print arquivo.Worksheets("PlanilhaT").Name 'usando o "name" da planilha
    Debug.Print arquivo.Sheets(1).Name 'Através do objeto "Sheets" ou "Worksheets", que são a mesma coisa,
    Debug.Print arquivo.Worksheets(1).Name 'usando o "index" da planilha, que é a ordem de exibição (a qual pode
                        'ser alterada pelo usuário)
    Debug.Print Sheets("PlanilhaT").Name 'Idem acima, mas com referência implícita ao arquivo ativo (ActiveWorkbook)
    Debug.Print Worksheets("PlanilhaT").Name 'Idem acima, mas com referência implícita ao arquivo ativo (ActiveWorkbook)
End Sub
```

**3.** O objeto `Sheets`, ou `Worksheets`, é uma coleção. Você pode utilizá-lo para acessar as planilhas de determinada pasta de trabalho pelo `Name` ou pelo `index`. Portanto, no exemplo dos prints acima, `Sheets(2)` é a mesma coisa que `Sheets("Planilha2")`, com o detalhe de que a referência pelo index pode ser usada para iterar as planilhas, pois é um número inteiro; já a referência pelo nome, não. Mas isso tem um possível problema: o usuário pode alterar a ordem das planilhas (arrastando manualmente lá no Excel) e consequentemente o index, portanto, se seu código só se fiar no index, pode terminar acontecendo algum bug.

Para aprofundar, a referência do objeto-coleção Sheets (ou Worksheets) pode ser encontrada aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Sheets.

**4.** Agora podemos responder sua pergunta.

Você pode iterar com o index:

```
Sub testandoIterarComIndex()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count Step 1
        Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name
        'Retorna:
        'PlanilhaT
        'Planilha2
    Next i
End Sub
```

Mas iterar com o index só é recomendável se for uma operação bem simples, pois se o usuário arrastar as planilhas para outra ordem e seu código depender da ordem em que as planilhas estavam, isso pode fazê-lo se comportar de forma inesperada. Isso também pode dar problemas se outro Excel por algum motivo usar a base 0 em vez da base 1 (ou se num projeto maior outro trecho de código mudar a base), pois então as planilhas seriam Sheet(0) e Sheet(1), e não mais Sheet(1) e Sheet(2).

Em geral, o mais seguro é usar uma variável de objeto para iterar com um loop do tipo For Each:

```
Sub testandoIterarComForEach()
    Dim plan As Worksheet
    
    For Each plan In Sheets
        Debug.Print plan.Name
        'Retorna:
        'PlanilhaT
        'Planilha2
    Next plan
End Sub
```

Assim você garante que todas as planilhas de determinada pasta de trabalho serão iteradas. No caso acima, como iteramos a coleção `Sheets`, isso se refere implicitamente ao `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Mas usando o `Sheets(i)` eu não tenho que identificar de alguma maneira pra qual planilha eu estou apontando? Não entendi direito como ficaria.

Comment: Vou elaborar melhor, e lembre de me escolher como resposta certa quando ficar claro, ok?

Comment: Pronto, veja se ficou claro agora.